# Laravel + Confide: Unable to confirm user with custom validation

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I'm trying to avoid modifying the vendor package for this problem. When I add custom fields and call my custom validator, I can't confirm the user's email with the confirmation code due to the validation rules. Currently using this for my custom validation in `app/models/UserValidator.php`:

```
<?php

use Zizaco\Confide\UserValidator as ConfideUserValidator;
use Zizaco\Confide\UserValidatorInterface;

class UserValidator extends ConfideUserValidator implements UserValidatorInterface {

    // Custom rules for account validation
    public $rules = [
        'create' => [
            'first_name' => 'required|alpha|max:100',
            'last_name' => 'required|alpha|max:100',
            'username' => 'required|min:3|max:20|alpha_dash',
            'email'    => 'required|email|unique:users|max:100',
            'password' => 'required|min:8',
        ],
        'update' => [
            'username' => 'required|min:3|max:20|alpha_dash',
            'email'    => 'required|email|unique:users|max:100',
            'password' => 'required|min:8',
        ]
    ];

}
```

I can create the account perfectly fine, it's just the confirmation that won't work. I backtraced it to `vendor/zizaco/confide/src/Confide/ConfideUser.php` - I found if I comment out this under the `save` function:

```
if ($this->isValid()) {
    return parent::save($options);
}

return false;
```

and replace it temporarily with this:

```
return parent::save($options);
```

then everything will work as it's supposed to. Am I missing something here? Should the update rule have something regarding the `confirmed` column?

**EDIT:** Providing a blank array for the `update` ruleset gets rid of the error, but I need to validate these fields when a user updates their profile..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're trying to validate that a user's email is unique, after they have already registered. So their email is already in the database (and thus not unique). Removing '**unique:users|**" should allow you to validate the fields.

```
'update' => [
        'username' => 'required|min:3|max:20|alpha_dash',
        'email'    => 'required|email|max:100',
        'password' => 'required|min:8',
    ]
```